# Informing polkadot/api about additional signed extensions

Tags: polkadot-js, signed-extensions

Polkadot/api has a way to detail signed extensions and I want to understand (so I can use it for our own custom signed extension) what the extrinsic and payload parameters map to.

Here's an example using some of the built in signed extensions (From: [substrate.ts](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/types/src/extrinsic/signedExtensions/substrate.ts))

```js
const api = await ApiPromise.create({
  signedExtensions: {
    CheckMortality: {
      extrinsic: {
        era: 'ExtrinsicEra'
      },
      payload: {
        blockHash: 'Hash'
      }
    },
    CheckNonce: {
      extrinsic: {
        nonce: 'Compact<Index>'
      },
      payload: {}
    }
});
```

These should both map to parts of the transaction format: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/transaction-format/#signed-extensions

My semi-wrong understanding currently:

- **Wrong**: `extrinsic`: Maps to the `Pre` section of the Signed Extension
- **Right?**: `payload`: Maps to the `AdditionalSigned` section of the Signed Extension

This doesn't quite work as [check_nonce.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b2a914c09739478c63d318f6b294901a3290e548/frame/system/src/extensions/check_nonce.rs#L67-L68) has `Pre = ();`

So how do I know that `CheckNonce` needs `extrinsic: { nonce }` for Polkadotjs or that `CheckMortality` needs `extrinsic: { era }`?

Nothing really appears to map to the `Pre` section of a signed extension, so also not sure how to tell polkadot/api about additional information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extrinsic` maps to the struct where the trait `SignExtension` is implemented. You can see it clearly comparing [`ChargeAssetTxPayment`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/frame/transaction-payment/asset-tx-payment/src/lib.rs#L148-L152) and its definition [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/8ba4ed53776a7a71478e229547c7af3d4dc57d63/packages/types/src/extrinsic/signedExtensions/statemint.ts#L7-L14)

You are right about `payload` mapping to `AdditionalSigned`