# how to pay transaction fee through custom token?

Tags: substrate-node-template, assets, signed-extensions, transaction-fees

i am working on substrate i have created a custom token using `pallet_assets`,how can i configure the transaction_fee using the custom token i have  seen the `pallet_assets_transaction payment` which say's [image]

i have added `pallet_asset_tx_payment` to my runtime Config and `construct_runtime` & `SignedExtension`

[image]

[image]

[image]

> **After above implementation when i try to transfer the assets from account A to account B the fees is getting deducted from the native
> token.**

i  tried to add into `pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime` can i do something like this?

```
type OnChargeTransaction = FungiblesAdapter<Balances,()>;
```

or is there any other way to do this? i have taken the reference from [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/how-to-pay-transaction-fees-using-the-custom-token-created-by-using-pallet-asset) but it did't work for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on "it didn't work"?

Comment: there was lots of errors,and i am not sure that is it the right way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not providing a lot of information it is hard to help you, but let me give you the main configurations you have to make in your `runtime/src/lib.rs`:

1. For paying fees with custom token you'd want the `pallet-asset-tx-payment` in stead of the `pallet-transaction-payment` (native token). You can implement it like its done in [Statemint](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/863e94d8627bfd30c61cf2aeac3b8706f768bb8f/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemint/src/lib.rs#L561-L573).
2. Adding it as a `SignedExtension`, [like so](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/blob/main/runtime/trappist/src/lib.rs#L98).
3. Adding it in the `construct_runtime`, [like so](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/863e94d8627bfd30c61cf2aeac3b8706f768bb8f/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemint/src/lib.rs#L626).

Comment: i have implemented all these three points but still when i create a asset using the pallet_assets the fees is getting deducted from the native token only.

for eg. I have created a custom token (PAT) if account A has 100 PAT token and 0 Native token then i am unable to transfer my (PAT) token to another account.Because the fees is deducted from the native token.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8063/where-do-i-add-a-signedextension-in-a-subxt-call ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i am using the substrate client where as in the question its subxt

Comment: [subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt): A library to submit extrinsics to a substrate node via RPC.

Comment: so do i need to add subxt into my substrate code ,can i do it without using subxt ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145399/discussion-between-daan-van-der-plas-and-amit-kumar-yadav).

Comment: This might help as well to make it work in polkadot js: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5695/informing-polkadot-api-about-additional-signed-extensions

Comment: `error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>: hidden_include::traits::fungible::Unbalanced<AccountId32>` is not satisfied. Getting this error, can someone face this error while configuring `pallet_asset_tx_payment`